# Form Validation error for required field in Dajango

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-forms

I have a html page where I am displaying text fileds are shown image [image: Screen]. Html code for this screen given below.

I want to display error message on screen if user enters invalid email id or email id existing on text filed of "Enter your Email" using forms validation error message. Currently I have written below piece of code display form validation error message. But this error message always displays just beside "New Password" test field. Is there any way I can display form validation error message beside "Email Your Mail" if user enters invalid email id or existing email id?

**HTML Code:**

```html
<fieldset class="module aligned wide">
{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.old_password.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.id_old_password.id_for_label }}">Old password:</label> {{ form.old_password }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.id_new_password1.id_for_label }}">New password:</label> {{ form.new_password1 }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.id_new_password2.id_for_label }}">Password (again):</label> {{ form.new_password2 }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
    {{ form.email_reset.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.email_reset.id_for_label }}">Enter Your Email (optional):</label> <input id="id_email_reset" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email_reset" type="email" pattern=".+@.+\.com"/>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

**Forms.py**

```html
class CustomPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    """ This is a customized class to validate the password by overriding
        the existing function "clean_new_password1" from base class PasswordChangeForm.
    """

    MIN_LENGTH = 8
    MAX_LENGTH = 64

    field_order = ['oldpassword', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')

        # At least MIN_LENGTH long
        if len(password1) < self.MIN_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The new password must be atleast %d characters long." % self.MIN_LENGTH)

        # At most MAX_LENGTH long
        if len(password1) > self.MAX_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The new password must be maximum %d characters long." % self.MAX_LENGTH)

        #if email id is given, then update it in database.
        if len(self.data['email_reset'].strip()) > 0:
            self.user.email = self.data['email_reset']

            if (User.objects.filter(email=self.user.email).count() > 1):
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email Id is already exist for different account. Please use different email id.")

        return password1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you have email validation in clean_password_new method? that is why all your errors displays at `password_new` field
do it in `clean` or in `clean_email_reset`
if you do it in `clean()` you can use `self.add_error("email_reset", "error message")`
or just copy all your code according to email validation into `clean_email_reset` method

Comment: I tried both methods clean_email_reset or clean. When I try with clean_email_reset, this method never called, not sure of exact reason. When I try with clean, then unable to display error message at text field email_reset on screen using method you suggested to add error. Just for your information, Password change form comes with only old password, password 1 and password 2. I have added email_reset by customizing password change form.

Comment: How did you add email_reset to your form? if you add it like this `email_reset = forms.CharField(label="Enter your e-mail", required=False)`, then you should get your error message with code, i posted in previous post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-row">
    {{form.old_password.label_tag}}
    {{form.old_password}}
    {% if form.old_password.errors %}
    {% for error in form.old_password.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger validation">
        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

`css`

```
.validation{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `alert alert-danger` is bootstrap classes